# AngularJS - Ng-repeat with radio buttons and boolean value

Tags: angularjs, radio-button, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array of `Book`-objects, each with the `boolean` property `Favorite`. Only one of the books has Favorite set to `true`.

I'm displaying these books using `ng-repeat`, and I want to be able to set the favorite book with radio buttons. However, even though the correct radio button is selected upon page load, the model doesn't update the boolean values when I select a different radio button.

Here's my code:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="book in vm.Books">
        {{book.Name}}
        <input name="book" type="radio" ng-model="book.Favorite" ng-value="book.Favorite" /> 
    </li>
<ul>
```

How do I update the model with the correct `Favorite`-value based on the checked radio button?

Comment: why do you have both value and model pointing to the same variable ? that way you are always setting value in book object to the value that this object has, so that's probably why...

Comment: remove `name="book"` as it should not be needed.  `ng-value="{{expression}}"` should not be a dynamic value from the model but some fixed unique value, like the `book.uniqueId`

Comment: @DarrylMiles But if I remove `name`, it allows me to check multiple radio boxes?

Comment: FWIW you'd expect model notion of favorite to be held outside of the `book` object itself. `ng-model="somethingelse.favorite" ng-value="book"` then fixup (convert to an ID) in controller during the load/store with storage.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D doesn't have that problem on FF at least (multiple radio buttons are set).  Maybe due to use of controller bound on `<form>` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is close, but will not set `book.Favorite` to `false` when  you pick another one (which I assume you want?):

```
<li ng-repeat="book in vm.Books">
  {{book.Name}}
  <input name="book" type="radio" ng-model="book.Favorite" ng-value="true">
</li>
```

I would just go this way instead:

```
<li ng-repeat="book in vm.Books">
  {{book.Name}}
  <input type="radio" ng-click="vm.setFavorite(book)" ng-checked="book.Favorite">
</li>
```

And:

```
vm.setFavorite = function(book) {

  vm.Books.forEach(function(b) {
    b.Favorite = book === b;
  });
};
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/UKGQW1dd8M5UiEbUCxWd?p=preview